# Sequelize inner join cannot get correct value

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize to query three models. They are company, product and subscription.

Company table:

```
Company_ID int primary_key
Copmany_Name varchar(20)
Email varchar(20)
```

Subscription table:

```
Subscription_ID int primary_key
Company_ID int foreign key of company table
Product_ID int foreign key of product table
Subscription_order int
```

Product table:

```
Product_ID int primary_key
Product_Name varchar(20)
```

my code for both model:

subscription model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
    sequelize.define(
        "Subscription",
        {
            subscriptionId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                field: "Subscription_ID",
            },
            companyId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: "Company_ID",
                references: {
                    model: "Company",
                    key: "companyId",
                },
            },
            productId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: "Product_ID",
                references: {
                    model: "Product",
                    key: "productId",
                },
            },
            orderId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: "Subscription_order",
            },
        },
        ...
```

Company model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
    sequelize.define(
        "Company",
        {
            companyId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                field: "Company_ID",
            },
            companyName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
                field: "Company_Name",
            },
            email: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
                field: "Email",
            },
        },
        ...
```

Product model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
    sequelize.define(
        "Product",
        {
            productId: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                allowNull: false,
                field: "Product_ID",
            },
            productName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
                field: "Product_Name",
            },
            ...
```

and the relationship I set is:

```
Subscription.hasMany(Company, { foreignKey: "companyId", as: "companies" })
Company.belongsTo(Subscription, { foreignKey: "companyId" })
Subscription.hasMany(Product, { foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" })
Product.belongsTo(Subscription, { foreignKey: "productId" })
```

on my controller:

```
const subscription = await Subscription.findAll({
            where: {
                companyId,
            },
            include: {
                model: Company,
            },
        })
res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: subscription })
```

I can get company detail like

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "data": {
        "companyId": 2,
        "companyName": "testCompany",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        }
}
```

and subscription detail itself when I test to read company detail and subscription detail separate, however, I always cannot show the joined company detail:

```
...
{
    "subscriptionId": 2,
    "companyId": 2,
    "productId": 5,
    "orderId": 4,
    "products": [
        {
            "productId": 2,
            "productName": "testProduct"
        }
    ],
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyId": 1,
            "companyName": "testcompany",
            "email": "testcompany@gmail.com",
        }
    ]
},
...
```

What I expect is like this, that what I use SQL query to do:

```
select * FROM Subscription subscription
INNER JOIN Company company on company.Company_ID = subscription.Company_ID
INNER JOIN Products products on products.Product_ID = subscription.Product_ID
where subscription.Company_ID= 2
```

That will retrun as the below which product id and company id are same:

```
...
{
    "subscriptionId": 2,
    "companyId": 2,
    "productId": 5,
    "orderId": 4,
    "products": [
        {
            "productId": 5,
            "productName": "testProduct"
        }
    ],
    "companies": [
        {
            "companyId": 2,
            "companyName": "testcompany",
            "email": "testcompany@gmail.com",
        }
    ]
},
...
```

I don't know why my sequelize include has different company id and product id for the individual part. What's wrong with my code?

I output the log and it says

```
FROM
    [Subscription] AS [Subscription]
INNER JOIN [Products] AS [products] ON
    [Subscription].[Subscription_ID] = [products].[Product_ID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [staging].[Dim_Company] AS [companies] ON
    [Subscription].[Subscription_ID] = [companies].[Company_ID]
```

Why it uses subscription_id?

Comment: you can try specify attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I missed sourceKey on relationship, the correct way is

```
Subscription.hasMany(Company, { sourceKey: "companyId", foreignKey: "companyId", as: "companies" })
Subscription.hasMany(Product, { sourceKey: "productId", foreignKey: "productId", as: "products" })
```

without sourceKey, sequelize by default will use primary key to join.